# Calculate growth rate of graph

Tags: graphing-functions

Lets make my scenario not generic just so that i could use particular terms

Say i have a graph of population per year of someplace over some decades

[Lets say the graph is like this](https://www.google.com.pk/publicdata/explore?ds=d5bncppjof8f9_&met_y=sp_pop_totl&tdim=true&dl=en&hl=en&q=total%20population%20of%20world#!ctype=l&strail=false&bcs=d&nselm=h&met_y=sp_pop_totl&scale_y=lin&ind_y=false&rdim=region&ifdim=region&tdim=true&hl=en_US&dl=en&ind=false)

Is there a way by which to put a number on speed of growth, not between two values, but for the graph as whole....